# textarea showing horizontal scroll bar after around 65k characters

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I found a Chrome bug, the `<textarea>` element, when either property `font-size` or `font-type` is specified, around 65k characters, a horizontal scroll bar shows up and no CSS properties successfully remove it. At the character that pushes it "over", when deleted, the scroll bar disappears. Why is this? Is it possible to stop this or know how to detect when it hits?

[image]

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. go to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea
2. add `style="font-size: 16px;"` to the `<textarea>`
3. Use either of these sample text, paste it into the text box
4. Press any text key (i.e. "t" or space)

**Visual Steps:**
[image]

English Text: https://gist.github.com/KevinDanikowski/f549cbb38e147e37cb9494d373d3615a

French Text: https://gist.github.com/KevinDanikowski/3834d1611eede4215e08ff3c860d09ee (the last character, "n" is the character that, when deleted, the scroll bar disappears).

PS: This didn't happen in firefox.

Comment: I don't have this problem.

Comment: @SecretTimes interesting, and you tried both texts? Becasue I did have other members of my team try it as well and they had the issue.

Comment: Yup, tried both texts and applied the ```font-size: 16px``` to ```<textarea>```

Comment: What version of Chrome are you working on?

Comment: @SecretTimes that's interesting, now I'm even more confused... Thank you tho, maybe it's an issue with my version, I'll update Chrome

Comment: @SecretTimes updating chrome solved the issue.... wow I feel dumb, that should of been the first thing I tried when I learned it was happening on chrome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238438/discussion-between-kevin-danikowski-and-secrettimes).

Answer (score 1):

This bug doesn't exist in the most up-to-date version of chrome. Just update Chrome.

Comment: Turns out this issue still happens in other scenarios even after updating. I don't have a new method to reproduce it so I'm not gonna worry about it for now